# AWS Lambda function is took long time to respond more than 1200 ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have deployed lambda with public access and inside the function validate the 'x-api-key' from the header.
When we ran the load test using this lambda function it took more than 1200 Milliseconds.
In the function, we have not implemented any time taking logic related to connecting to a database or getting responses from any other lambda, etc., but still, it is taking more time.
Please help me what would be the cause to take more time.

```
exports.token = async (event) => {
const service_name = event.pathParameters['servicename'];
let headers = event.headers;

... Some logic to validate the body parameter and x-api-key from header...
try {
        //Validates the public key
        if (public_token != process.env.publickeyvalue) {
            return as Forbidden
        }

        ...

        console.debug('*** TOKEN_API - End ***')
        //if public key is valid, return the private key
        return token to client
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.debug('TOKEN_API - Error', e);
        return as Operationfailed
    }



}
```

Comment: If it is called a second time, does it still take that long? Is the function connect to a VPC (presumably not)? What timing does it show in CloudWatch Logs for Start & End time of the function?

Comment: Yes, I have deployed the function in the VPC environment. We are using the Gatling tool for the load it always shows my function taking more than 1200 ms even executing 5th time also.

Comment: Does it _require_ connectivity to any resources in the VPC? If not, you can disconnect it and it avoids creation of the Elastic Network Interface. Admittedly, that should only be required on "first execution". What timing does it show in CloudWatch Logs for Start & End time of the function? This will help identify whether the time is taken _inside_ the function, or for environment creation _outside_ of the function. How is the function being invoked?

Comment: This function is not using any resources in the VPC. But other APIs using the resource in the VPC. Cloudwatch time taken is 30ms and API Gateway time taken is 750ms. other APIs are taking less than 1200ms in a load test. other APIs using elastic search, SQS calls.